# cooktop burner cycling on and off

Tags: stove

I have a Kitchenaid cooktop model KECC567 (5 burner model) with a 2 element burner that will not cycle on or off no matter what control switch setting is used. The 2 elements of the burner stay on continuously when the dual side is selected as does the single element when it is selected on the switch. I have replaced the infinite switch but the problem still exists. Appreciate some suggestions on resolution of this problem. Has to be a temperature sensor but don't know where to look for it.  Thanks

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your stove? (It should be on one of the inside panels somewhere)

Comment: How do you know the elements are suppposed to cycle? They may very well be designed to run at continuous current, not a set temperature point.  Take a look at the owner's manual for starters.

Comment: Burners needs to cycle on and off to prevent overheating the ceran glass cover similar to what the other 4 burners on the cooktop do. Turns out the infinite switch on the 2 coil burner was faulty. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

This is for future reference in case anyone is looking for similar information. The OP noted in a comment that

> the infinite switch on the 2 coil burner was faulty.

So, it should indeed cycle

> to prevent overheating the ceran glass cover similar to what the other 4 burners on the cooktop do.

<sup><sub>P.S. Marking this CW since it isn't really my answer.</sub></sup>

Answer (score -1):

Well, I looked at the manual, at [this site](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/www.mrcdn.com/pdf/kitchenaid/kitchenaid-kecc056-kecc506-kecc507-kecc508-kecc556-kecc567-kecc548-kecc558-users-manual-265006.pdf)
, and I see no indication that the power should ever cycle on/off.
I think you misunderstand what the various settings levels do -- they just control the power level fed to the burners.

Comment: That's correct but the burner needs to cycle on and off to prevent overheating the ceran glass cover similar to what the other 4 burners on the cooktop do. Turns out the infinite switch on the 2 coil burner was faulty.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: @KellyHawk good to know.  You should post that as an answer for future readers.  I'll delete my answer after that.